# How to fix "let i = 0 " value in "for" loops go to 0 again after finish looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I use `for` loop with `let i = 0` as counter after `i` value pass the max value in `for` loops example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 60; i++)
```

The max value is `59`. The `i` value back again to `0`. What's wrong  with the code ?

I debugging with `console.log()` to check the value in every loops and array, but I still don't understand why the `i` value back again to `0` and start looping again.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let val = 0;
  let valu = [];

  // Make an array contain every word length 
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let a = str.split("")[i];

    if (a == " ") {
      valu.push(val);
      val = 0;
    } else {
      val++;
    }
    
    console.log(i);
  }
  
  val = 0;

  // Search for the max value 
  for (let i = 0; i < valu.length; i++) {
    if (valu[i] > val) {
      val = valu[i];
    }
  }

  return val;
}

findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
console.log(findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology"));
```

And this is the result in the console:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
```

I expect the output to be `19`, but the actual output is `4`

Comment: the only problem with your function is that `valu` never includes the length of the final word, because you only push that on to the array if you encounter a space character - which obviously doesn't happen at the end. You could have figured this out yourself with some elementary debugging.

Comment: The output of your script is neither `19` nor `4`, it's `10`

Comment: The value of `i` goes "back" to 0 because of `let i = 0` and because you're calling the function twice, so there are two `i` variables, both starting from 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in you code is that the last string will not be added to `valu` array because to add to length to `valu` array condition `if (a === " ")` should be `true`. For last word it never gets true because there is no `" "` after it.

You should add `val` into `valu` after the loop finishes. See the below snippet.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let val = 0;
  let valu = [];
  let arr = str.split('');
  // Make an array contain every word length 
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let a = arr[i];

    if (a === " ") {
      valu.push(val);
      val = 0;
    } else {
      val++;
    }
  }
  valu.push(val) // this line is only added line by me.
  val = 0;

  // Search for the max value 
  for (let i = 0; i < valu.length; i++) {
    if (valu[i] > val) {
      val = valu[i];
    }
  }

  return val;
}

findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
console.log(findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology"));
```

> The max value is 59. The i value back again to 0. What's wrong with the code ?

Because the variable `i` is local variable and each time loop starts its initialized to the value `0`.

#### Better way

A simple code is to `split()` string by `" "` and then `map()` it the `length` of each word and then pass it to `Math.max()` using Spread Syntax

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  return Math.max(...str.split(' ').map(x => x.length))
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after for loop:

```
valu.push(val);
```

You got the wrong answer since the last "val" is not added to the array in the last loop. Be careful of i lesser than the str length and your if condition.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let val = 0;
  let valu = [];

  // Make an array contain every word length 
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let a = str.split("")[i];

    if (a == " ") {
      valu.push(val);
      val = 0;
    } else {
      val++;
    }

    console.log(i);
  }

  // Add this line to add the last value "val".
  valu.push(val);

  val = 0;

  // Search for the max value 
  for (let i = 0; i < valu.length; i++) {
    if (valu[i] > val) {
      val = valu[i];
    }
  }

  return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed adding the last word to array in the code you posted.

For the same problem, we can achieve it using below code

1) Using For Loop

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length > longestWord){
    longestWord = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
findLongestWord("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

2) Using the sort method

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; });
  return longestWord[0].length;
}
findLongestWord("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

3) Using the reduce method

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord.length;
}
findLongestWord("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can take to solve this in a single line is to utilize [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in a `descending order` and simply pick the first element. If you start by splitting the sentence on white space (via [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) you would get an array with each of the words. Then order them via checking each word length:

```js
let str = 'What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology'

let result = str.split(' ').sort((a,b) => b.length - a.length)[0]

console.log(result) // <-- longest word
console.log(result.length) // <-- word length
```

If you wanted to find the shortest word simply change the sort logic to be `a.length - b.length` etc.